# How to load faster a page using AJAX in sinatra

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinatra

I am developing a project (URL: example) and I have a form which loads many options (more than 6000) in many rows (20) of a table.

The table is something like this:

```
User    role    permission     machine
```

In the machine column there is a form like this:

```
<form action="/example" method="get">
 <select>
   <% session[:var].map(&:to_i).sort.each do |var| %>
     <option><%= var.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8') %></option>
   <%end%>
 </select>
</form>
```

The problem is when accessing the URL, it takes to much loading all the data in the machine column because of the `var` variable which loads all the machines. (size of this call 3.2 Mb).

When the user selects an option then the page loads again. But in this point I can use AJAX to avoid this refreshing when the user selects an option.

**My question is:**

Is it possible also with AJAX to make faster the page just when typing the URL (example) or there is any form to accelerate this loading process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefill the results of the first visible page (say, 25 results), and then *either* paginate the results, thus allowing for refreshes but cutting down on the data for each response, *or* use AJAX to update the results as they scroll / push an update button. Most of the database ORM libraries have a pagination plugin you can use.

There's nothing here that *needs* AJAX though. Remember that AJAX is just making calls to the site API, there's nothing special about it, it's still just a bunch of HTTP calls asking for a response. AJAX gives you the opportunity to stagger some of them by pushing some of the processing on to the client side, that's the main thing.

Consider splitting up your routes/apps into those that provide pages and those that provide data only. You can even combine routes that provide rendering and data by [using the `request.xhr?` object method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates), e.g.

```
erb :index, :layout => !request.xhr?
```

or

```
if request.xhr?
  json {my: data, goes: here}
else
  erb :index, :locals => {my: data, goes: here}
end
```

> When the user selects an option then the page loads again

You could definitely use AJAX here to avoid page refresh - they already have the data, so why refresh?